# Does "Katamari Damacy" actually translate to anything?

Tags: katamari-damacy

I was wondering about this. I kind of doubt a katamari is a real thing, so maybe the word "katamari" is a made up, compound-y kind of word? That's what I'm guessing.

Anyway, does katamari damacy actually mean anything?

Comment: Sounds like you are missing out on the awesomeness of Wikipedia: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Katamari_Damacy

Comment: Ah. How did I miss that.

Comment: @JamesJiao Why not make that an answer? =)

Comment: And now, the main theme is stuck in my head. Thank you.

Comment: Naaaaaa na na na na na naa naa na ka-ta-ma-ri da-ma-sheeeeeeee

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Katamari Damacy is the English adaptation of the Japanese romaji *Katamari Damashī* (kanji: 塊魂, hiragana: かたまり だましい), which means **lump/chunk soul**.

Comment: The two Kanji are not used together usually. The originality of the title is that it is made of two Kanji that share a common radical, 鬼 (おに, oni).

Comment: @wip That's actually the phonetic not the radical. Radicals indicate the meaning and phonetics give clues to the pronunciation.

Comment: Thank you for the information.

In the material I had availalble 旁(つくり) was translated as "radical", like is also done here for example: https://kanjialive.com/214-traditional-kanji-radicals/

You raise an interesting point regarding prononciation, I searched and it seems the 旁 "鬼" has a number of 音読み: https://kanji.jitenon.jp/cat/bushu10004.html